# Does anyone know how to change or add some theme in Notepad++ x64?

Tags: notepad++

I'm looking for way to change the theme in 64-bit version. I know, there is the 'themes' folder in x86. In x64 there is no one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add the theme plug-in(which is xml file) inside the plugin folder of the notepad ++.

[image]

So to get the theme for notepad x64 bit visit here.

https://github.com/bruderstein/npp-plugins-x64/blob/master/plugins/plugins64.xml